# react-native android shows blur(foggy) view on samsuns-10 device,

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-components

I haven't use any blur effect but in my samsung device it showing foggy view foggy image

[image: 1]

I have trying to refresh the view but not getting proper solution

Comment: Hello, 
You should also show us how it should really look.

Also, you should share more details, maybe sample of code, which components, which libraries you're using

Comment: hi @FreakyCoder thanks for your reply well i have used hit and trial method and resolve by using pressable instead of touchableOpacity